# Substring a money value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i'm trying to substring a value (money 1000.99). I want to take everything before the .99 and the take everything after the 1000. also the value could be anything ie 100.00, 1100.00

I have tried this but not quite working

```
%%[
SET @NCBestPrice1 = NCBestPrice1
SET @NCBestPrice1Fix = FormatNumber(@NCBestPrice1fix,"F2")
SET @NCBestPrice1Pounds = Substring(@NCBestPrice1fix, 0, Subtract(Length(@NCBestPrice1fix),3))
SET @NCBestPrice1Pence = Substring(@NCBestPrice1fix,Add(Length(@NCBestPrice1Pounds),1), 3)
]%%
```

Getting this error:

> Unable to generate preview A scripting error has occurred. An error
>   occurred when attempting to evaluate a FormatNumber function call. The
>   input value () cannot be formatted as a number. The first parameter
>   value for a FormatNumber call must be a numeric type supported by the
>   requested format. Value:  Format: F2

The Data extension field is Text(100).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't `SET @NCBestPrice1Fix = FormatNumber(@NCBestPrice1fix,"F2")` be this: `SET @NCBestPrice1Fix = FormatNumber(@NCBestPrice1 ,"F2")`?

Answer (score 1):

You might be better served by the [IndexOf()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#IndexOf) function.

```
%%[
var @NCBestPrice1, @NCBestPrice1Fix, @NCBestPrice1Pounds, @NCBestPrice1Pence
SET @NCBestPrice1 = "1000"
SET @NCBestPrice1Fix = FormatNumber(@NCBestPrice1,"F2")
SET @NCBestPrice1Pounds = Substring(@NCBestPrice1fix, 0, Subtract(indexOf(@NCBestPrice1Fix,"."),1))
SET @NCBestPrice1Pence = Substring(@NCBestPrice1fix,IndexOf(@NCBestPrice1Fix,"."),length(@NCBestPrice1))

]%%
<br>@NCBestPrice1: %%=v(@NCBestPrice1)=%%
<br>@NCBestPrice1Fix: %%=v(@NCBestPrice1Fix)=%%
<br>@NCBestPrice1Pounds: %%=v(@NCBestPrice1Pounds)=%%
<br>@NCBestPrice1Pence: %%=v(@NCBestPrice1Pence)=%%
```

**Output**

```
@NCBestPrice1: 1000 
@NCBestPrice1Fix: 1000.00 
@NCBestPrice1Pounds: 1000 
@NCBestPrice1Pence: .00
```

With an alternate input:

```
%%[
var @NCBestPrice1, @NCBestPrice1Fix, @NCBestPrice1Pounds, @NCBestPrice1Pence
SET @NCBestPrice1 = "100.99"
SET @NCBestPrice1Fix = FormatNumber(@NCBestPrice1,"F2")
SET @NCBestPrice1Pounds = Substring(@NCBestPrice1fix, 0, Subtract(indexOf(@NCBestPrice1Fix,"."),1))
SET @NCBestPrice1Pence = Substring(@NCBestPrice1fix,IndexOf(@NCBestPrice1Fix,"."),length(@NCBestPrice1))

]%%
<br>@NCBestPrice1: %%=v(@NCBestPrice1)=%%
<br>@NCBestPrice1Fix: %%=v(@NCBestPrice1Fix)=%%
<br>@NCBestPrice1Pounds: %%=v(@NCBestPrice1Pounds)=%%
<br>@NCBestPrice1Pence: %%=v(@NCBestPrice1Pence)=%%
```

**Output**

```
@NCBestPrice1: 100.99 
@NCBestPrice1Fix: 100.99 
@NCBestPrice1Pounds: 100 
@NCBestPrice1Pence: .99
```